# Why doesn't SDL_Surface rendering work in SDL2?

Tags: c++, image, sdl2

I have done the following using C++:

1) I used `SDL_CreateWindow()` to create an SDL window

```
m_window = SDL_CreateWindow("My First Side-scroller
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH,
    SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
```

2) I used `SDL_CreateRenderer()` to create a renderer for the SDL window

```
m_renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(m_window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
```

3) I used `SDL_CreateTexture()` to create a texture

```
m_texture = SDL_CreateTexture(m_renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888,
        SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
```

4) I created a buffer of type `Uint32` to hold texture information which is passed to the `SDL_Texture`

```
m_buffer = new Uint32[SCREEN_WIDTH * SCREEN_HEIGHT];
```

5) I created a custom pixel drawing function which is use to draw pixels at a low level and pass it to the buffer.

```
void Screen::setPixel(int x, int y, Uint8 red, Uint8 green, Uint8 blue) {
    // Checking for pixels  off screen 
    // This is sufficient because the rand function can generate a negative number
    if (x < 0 || x >= SCREEN_WIDTH || y < 0 || y >= SCREEN_HEIGHT) {
        return;
    }

    Uint32 colour = 0;

    colour += red;
    colour <<= 8;
    colour += green;
    colour <<= 8;
    colour += blue;
    colour <<= 8;
    colour += 0xFF;

    m_buffer[(y * SCREEN_WIDTH) + x] = colour;
}
```

6) I used 5) along with other functions to help draw pixels on random locations in the window and make them move vertically and loop from the top of the window to the bottom of the window (like moving stars).

```
Stars::Stars()
{
    m_x_star=((2.0*rand())/RAND_MAX)-1;
    m_y_star=((2.0*rand())/RAND_MAX)-1;
}

void Stars::moveStar(){
    // starSpeed is the desired change in co-ordinate position for each pixel plotted
    double const starSpeed = 0.001;


    if(m_y_star<-0.998 && m_y_star>-1) {
        m_y_star=0.995;
    }

    m_y_star-=starSpeed;
}
```

1) to 6) works with no-error

So, onto my issue: Blitting an image using `SDL_BlitSurface` seems to require that the window is created using SDL_Surface() for its third flag. I want to load a .png image of a spaceship I drew. Here is the code I use to load the image.

```
void Screen::update_spaceShip() {
    SDL_Surface *Image;
    Image= IMG_Load("spaceship_stock2.png");
    SDL_BlitSurface(Image,NULL,m_window,NULL);
}
```

Error message:

> cannot convert 'SDL_Window*' to 'SDL_Surface*' for argument '3' to 'int SDL_UpperBlit(SDL_Surface*, const SDL_Rect*, SDL_Surface*, SDL_Rect*)'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for [`SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface). As you seem to have learned (the hard way), SDL2 doesn't really support rendering surfaces directly anymore. There are ways to do that I believe, but you should be using hardware rendering, which is implemented using surfaces. So, the modern way is to load a surface, convert that into a texture that you can use and then get rid of the surface. So something like

```
SDL_Surface* image = IMG_Load("yourimage.png");
SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(m_Renderer, image);
SDL_FreeSurface(image);
```

So, you can load a surface using `IMG_Load` and then convert that into a texture that you can render using `SDL_RenderCopy` or I believe SDL_Image even comes with a `IMG_LoadTexture` these days.
You should note that calling `IMG_Load` in your render-method is a bad idea as it allocates memory each time, so you want to do this at initialization instead.

I recommend you do some reading on the `SDL_Renderer` and it's uses. However, if you are insistent on using `SDL_BlitSurface` instead of the faster new way to render, please let me know.

Comment: I now get an error on the line "SDL_Surface* image = IMG_Load("yourimage.png");stating the following" stating the f

Comment: @TheAce You have a typo. :)

Comment: I now get an error on the line "SDL_Surface* image = IMG_Load("yourimage.png");stating that there is an 'undefined reference to IMG_Load'.  I have the following DLL's in my  debug folder. libjpeg-9dll, libpng16-16.dll, SDL2_image.dll, SDL2.dll. My spaceship_stock2.png file is the destination folder. I have included the following flags in my Libraries: mingw32, SDL2main, SDL2, SDL2_image in that order. I've set the paths for the library and includes aswell as copied all of the necessary files from SDL_image into the correct folder. ...MinGW\include\SDL2 and ...MinGW\lib.

Comment: I'm not sure about that @TheAce, there seem to be a lot of resources about that specific error on the internet though, so Google might be your best bet here.

Comment: *ive also added zlib1.dll to my debug and release folder

Comment: I hate SDL renderer, it goes against everything my code uses, using the renderer to draw one single line means i have to rewrite 5000 lines of code, is it possible to draw a simple line without the faffaround of breaking every single damn thing with a stupid renderers?

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with the answer here, @Owl? If you are having issues with something other than what OP asked about, you should post a question about that.

Comment: @TheAce That's - as you maybe figured out by now - a linker error. I don't use Windows so I can't really help there (assuming you even need it still) but it's a matter of making sure to link in the right library so that when compiling the compiler/linker will be able to find the function. Mingw32? Is that a Unix like port? If so you might have to update your `LDFLAGS`. Probably no longer necessary but fwiw that's the general idea.